# Can I power up my Arduino and MotorShield with four AA batteries?

Tags: arduino-uno

can I power up my Arduino UNO with four AA batteries? It's about 6V, will my arduino burn? And, if I power my Arduino, I have to power my Motor Shield too or not?

I want to make line follower. I have to know what I have to power up. I dont know, how many battery holders I need. I have: Arduino UNO, motor shield, two 6V DC motors

Comment: connect 4 AA batteries through the power jack. nothing will get burned. Please share which motor shield you are using

Comment: this one: https://goo.gl/XbYSx0 ; and I have two DC motors (6V), btw, I have battery without ON/OFF switch, if I plug it in power jack, and after minute suddenly I disconnect this jack, will it damage my Arduino? is there other option? btw how many volts can I connect to this power jack?

Comment: L293d can support upto 36V. (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf)
arduino Uno: Input Voltage (recommended) 7-12V
Input Voltage (limit) 6-20V

Comment: @Sanu-OpenMaker I have to give power to Arduino Uno, Motor shield and two motors? so I need 3 battery holders?

Comment: Generally No need. You can give 6V to arduino through power jack. Arduino has a voltage regulator to convert to 5v. 

Motors driver will get powerder through Vin pin in arduino(in some other cases you can connect 6V to the shield and it will power the arduino as well)

Motors are gerring power from motor driver in most cases

Answer (score 1):

You won't damage the Arduino if you remove the power to the motors as even though you're using the same power supply to power the motots and Arduino (4 x 1.5 - 6V batteries) you're not powering it from the Arduino pins itself.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  Post some more info.

Comment: I updated question

Answer (score 0):

> can I power up my Arduino UNO with four AA batteries?

6v is about the max if it is directly applied to the chip;

6v is just shy of the minimum if it is applied to a regulator and then to the chip.

Comment: This is multiply mistaken.  6v is too low for the usual regulator to deliver rated output.  But 6v is also not the sum of four new alkaline AA's, which will be higher.

Answer (score 0):

It won't cause damage to connect 4xAA to the input of the Arduino's regulator, however it also won't result in specified operation, as even with fairly new cells the voltage will below that which the typically used 5v regulators require to deliver 5v at the output.

Additionally, the common L293D and L298 based bipolar motor shields are horribly lossy.  Feed them about 6v input, and you'll get just over 4v to your motor, which is likely to be disappointing.

To build an Arduino-based battery-powered motor project, you typically need to do one of two things

- Use 6, 7, 8 or more cells, and higher-voltage, lower current motors
- Use a 3.3v Arduino and a more efficient FET-based H-bridge motor driver/shield, for example the TB6612FNG.   This supports 4 cell operation quite well, and may to a more limited degree work on 3 *alkaline* cells.